# How to run several commands using ssh and android in only one session?

Tags: android, ssh

I've used this [SSH with JSCH](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14323661/simple-ssh-connect-with-jsch?rq=1&newreg=f457fbe7ed3a4f0ea535508a2fec84a5) in my android project.
But I want to run two commands for example:

```
$ cd Desktop

$ ls
```

I`ve already tried to append more strings in one Method but it didn`t help...

so how can I do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well I solved the issue.
Just for other people searching for the question I wanted to let you know, that you can easily Add a new Command with

```
.addCommand("newCommand")
```